# How to to import JS file in QML when using the Tumblr API?

Tags: javascript, api, qml, tumblr

I'd like to write a QML application for Tumblr.

I try simply to copy paste code from the Console examples but obviously it has not worked. I can't find if I have to download something or I don't know...the problem seemed to be require(): QtCreator tells me

```
"ReferenceError: require is not defined".
```

So, in conclusion, there's a guide from very very new users about these things? I would like to read a step by step guide for what I have to do, what I have to download where I have to put the files, etc.

Comment: The documentation on the Qt website is really good and you should start here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/qtquick-applicationdevelopers.html

Comment: My problem isn't focused on QML, I know how to importo JS file in QML, JS file in another JS file ecc. My question is about how API works? Do I have to download something? What do I have to do with the require problem? :)

Comment: Ok it seems that Tumblr uses RequireJS (http://requirejs.org/) so you might need to use it in your QML app or maybe modify the tumblr API js file to avoid using the require statement (which is not a javascript keyword)

Comment: so I have simply to download the file and import it in the js file where I use tumbler's api?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the documentation of RequireJS and trying with a simple example (simpler than Tumblr) at first to see if it works in QML

Comment: I don't know, I only want to use tumblr API...I mean, do I really need to get interested in require? I only want to be able to repeat on my coputer what tumblr shows here https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/user/info ,I've downloaded the file for require and I get Error: Module name "tumblr.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded . do I need this https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.js ? How do I use it?

Comment: As I told you, the issue is that Tumblr relies on requirejs so yes you need to understand it or find a way to use Tumblr API without it. Another possibility is to look at the Tumblr API calls and rewrite your own API for it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the page explaining some subtleties of QtQuick Javascript's implementation: [Integrating Javascript](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativejavascript.html)

You should especially read the sections:

- Stateless JavaScript libraries
- Importing One JavaScript File From Another

I don't know the internals of the tumblr API or require.js, but if those use browser-specific stuff, they won't work with the Qml engine.

You'll then have some solutions:

- use the python tumblr api + pyqt (doesn't support QtQuick2 yet, but this should come with the next pyqt5 version) or the ruby version (qt4 only)
- deal with tumblr's api in c++ (but I don't think they provide a convenient api?)
- use tumblr's rest api from qml/javascript "by-hand" (using XmlHttpRequest and JSON.parse() from the global qml object)

Answer (score 0):

Well, regarding the *require* issue the thing is that the tumblr.js library works over nodejs as you can see from another frustrated user here [Tumblr.js API -- require() fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514506/tumblr-js-api-require-fails)